# fiji plugin : imgOpener exception (scifio class)

Tags: image, image-processing, plugins, bioinformatics, imagej

I'm using Fiji for the first time, I need to open an image as a FloatType so I followed the example found here http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/ImgLib2_Examples#Example_1b_-_Opening_an_ImgLib2_image but I get this error:

```
WARN: Ignoring non-Maven build directory: /home/utente/workspace/my_project/bin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No compatible service:  io.scif.SCIFIOService
at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadService(ServiceHelper.java:222)
at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadService(ServiceHelper.java:176)
at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadServices(ServiceHelper.java:153)
at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:200)
at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:127)
at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:116)
at io.scif.img.AbstractImgIOComponent.<init>(AbstractImgIOComponent.java:65)
at io.scif.img.ImgOpener.<init>(ImgOpener.java:99)
at SGP_db.StartingJFrame.getGn(StartingJFrame.java:216)
at Plugin.SGP_deblurring_boundary.main(SGP_deblurring_boundary.java:58)
```

Can't undertand why I get this error, any ideas?

Thanks,

sara

Comment: Can you please provide more details about how your project is structured? Are you using Eclipse? Trying to run from Fiji's Script Editor? Using a different IDE? Or running from the command line?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse for writing and running my program. I may have done some mistake configuring my project build path..anyway I've solved importing the ImgOpener class from imglib2.io .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost certainly a build path issue in Eclipse. Are you using the M2E plugin to manage your projects?

If you are not, or aren't sure, please follow the directions on the Fiji web site at:

- http://fiji.sc/Developing_ImgLib2#Developing_ImgLib2_with_Eclipse

I would strongly suggest not to manually juggle JAR files in non-Maven Eclipse projects. The Eclipse Maven integration will make your life *much* easier. For more details, see:

- http://fiji.sc/Maven

> I've solved importing the ImgOpener class from imglib2.io

Please note that `imglib2-io` no longer exists; the up-to-date way to access the `ImgOpener` is to use the `io.scif:scifio` library instead. If you are basing your work off of the [ImgLib2 Examples](http://fiji.sc/ImgLib2_Examples), please note that you can [grab the source from GitHub](https://github.com/imagej/imglib/tree/imglib2-2.0.0-beta-22/examples), which includes a [Maven POM](https://github.com/imagej/imglib/blob/imglib2-2.0.0-beta-22/examples/pom.xml) with the correct dependencies specified. Start from there, or from the [minimal-ij1-plugin](https://github.com/imagej/minimal-ij1-plugin) project if you need to use ImageJ 1.x routines as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already had the maven integration; it was sufficent to fix some warngings about my project directory and include the pom file, now it works!

Comment: With eclipse now I can compile and run the plugin correctly but running it on Fiji I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:3 when opening a tif image (0 with jpg) at RandomAccessConverter.getPosition(122) from RandomAccessConverter.populatePlane(86). I simply use the method: new ImgOpener().openImg(filePath, new ArrayImgFactory(), new FloatType()) as shown in the examples. Hope you can help me, searching on the net nothing was useful @ctrueden

Comment: It is probably because Fiji still ships SCIFIO 0.7.1 rather than [version 0.7.4](http://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/releases/io/scif/scifio/0.7.4/). Many bugs, including some related to RGB images, were fixed in the interim. Can you please test with SCIFIO 0.7.4 (delete the scifio-0.7.1.jar in your jars folder and put scifio-0.7.4 there instead) and let me know if fixed? If so, I will upload that version to Fiji. Thanks!

Comment: @sara Actually, it may still be an active bug. See [GitHub issue #111](https://github.com/scifio/scifio/issues/111). If you want to be kept informed of progress, just write a comment onto the issue and GitHub will start emailing you when the issue changes.

Comment: you were right..it was enough to change the jar file to version 0.7.4 and the scijava-common jar file to version 2.6.1, thanks a lot!